# wonder if my MOBO and CPU are gonna support specific RAM ?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, upgrade, compatibility

My MOBO currently has 16GB RAM 1600MHz installed and the CPU is intel i5-2300 core.
 I decided to upgrade to 32GB RAM.
The MOBO is **GA-z68x-ud4-b3** and it supports variety of RAM speeds, but my CPU supports **officially only up to 1333MHz**.
So am I really restricted to 1333MHz RAM or is it gonna support above that too (1600MHz or 1866MHz for instance) too ?
I don't want to upgrade the CPU at the moment and I'm not an "overclocker", just want an upgraded RAM.
BTW, the BIOS seems to recognize my current RAM as running in 1600MHz indeed.

Comment: According to Itel 1333 is max speed for that processor, no way around it...https://ark.intel.com/products/52206/Intel-Core-i5-2300-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3-10-GHz-